# Query MySQL count data & turn into JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json, datetime, count

My table contains a column of '*datetimes*', with an id.

```
+----+---------------------+
| id |      datetime       |
+----+---------------------+
| 0  | 2016-09-02 12:13:13 |
| 1  | 2016-09-02 10:16:11 |
| 2  | 2016-09-05 11:03:23 |
| 3  | 2016-09-08 11:34:45 |
| 4  | 2016-09-08 09:23:06 |
| 5  | 2016-09-08 10:22:05 |
| .. |         ...         |
+----+---------------------+
```

There will be multiple instances of each date in the table. My aim is to gather the amount of times each date occurs. So for the table above:

```
2016-09-02 => 2
2016-09-05 => 1
2016-09-08 => 3
```

I then need to move the data into JSON format using PHP like so:

```
[{"date":"2016-09-02","count":"2"},
 {"date":"2016-09-05","count":"1"},
 {"date":"2016-09-08","count":"3"}]
```

The JSON format will be used by a **d3.js** script I have written to plot each date against the frequency each date occurs.

I have never dealt with this kind of query before so I really have no idea where to start, or how to use PHP to move into JSON format. Thank you to anyone that can help.

Comment: Use `COUNT(*)` and `GROUP BY`. This is really basic SQL, it should be in many tutorials.

Comment: SO is not a code-writing service or a tutoring service. You need to learn the basics and write the code yourself. If you can't get it working, post your attempt here and we'll help you.

Comment: Also for moving your otuput to JSON is pretty simple... check the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%Y-%m-%d') AS `date`,
       COUNT(*) AS `count`
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Then create the JSON in your PHP code:

```
$a = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $a[] = array('date' => "$row['date']", 'count' => "$row['count']");
}

$json = json_encode($a);
```

Comment: It seems like the SQL query would return the specified result. I'm not sure why this answer receives a downvote. +10.

Comment: Thank you, this worked great. I managed to figure out the SQL but wasn't sure how to create the JSON using PHP. This helped wonders.

Answer (score 0):

I think below SQL useful to you. please run and see

```
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%Y-%m-%d'),count(*)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY 1
order by 1
```